# execute powershell ps1 script with windows 2012 task scheduler

Tags: powershell-3.0

I am trying to launch ffmpeg process to convert online audio video streams after fix interval of time. Following script is working when running from powershell editor or powershell command window. But when I am running it with task scheduler after it executed with success I can't find(powershell get-procces) any ffmpeg process running. I am pulling my hair now. I have configured this task in task scheduler with admin account.

```
get-process -name ffmpeg | stop-process
#get-process -name powershell | Stop-Process



Start-Job -ScriptBlock {ffmpeg -re -i http://bgsf.hls.iptvdc.com/islambox/732/play.m3u8 -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ab 48k -ac 2 -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://192.168.1.2/live/najam83}
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {ffmpeg -re -i http://bgsf.redist.iptvdc.com/islambox/969ecd6cb9e136ed0fd042ccf5cc057b -c:v copy -c:a aac -ar 48000 -ab 48k -ac 2 -strict -2 -f flv rtmp://ib12.islambox.tv/live/najam84}
```

Comment: Add lots of logging, with a transcript, to your script. Likely something is failing due to the different context/session it is running in.

Comment: can you tel me how to log? and where i can view the log?

Comment: `Write-Debug`, `Write-Verbose` having set the right [preference variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847796.aspx), Also [`Start-Transscript`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849687.aspx).

Comment: I think this line is creating problem when task scheduler is invoking powershell script. I am concluding this by the fact when i run script manually two ffmpeg process got created and visible to get-process -name ffmpeg command. Now task scheduler execute powershell script first line kills every ffmpeg process. I verified this just now and coudnt find my two ffmpeg process anymore. Next step was creating ffmpeg process again which is not happening. So issue is start-job. How can i move from start-job to start-process?

Comment: That question comes down to the details of what you are trying to do. But in the end you are currently guessing: you might accidentally hit on something that works, but you won't really know unless you know why other options are failing.

Comment: can you help me with replacing start-job line to start-process? what change do i need to make. maybe that works.

Comment: No I can't quickly. But that is the wrong thing to do: work out what is not working first. Then change to fix that. Repeat until all working.